# Draw a circuit in Physics

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Could you show me how to draw this. Please Kindly help me. Thank in advanced.
[image]

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: I'm a first user. That I try to learn with latex. Please show me one on this.

Comment: See `circuitikz` package. Here is a lot of examples of their use. Your scheme is quite elementary ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0)   to[ammeter]          ++ (1.5,0)
                to[generic, l=R]    ++ (2.5,0)
        (0,0)   to[short,-*]        ++ (0.0,1.5)  coordinate (v)
                to[voltmeter,-*]    ++ (4,0)
        (v)     to[short]           ++ (0,1.5)
                to[V=E, invert]     ++ (4,0)
                to[short,-*]        ++ (0,-1.5)
                -- ++ (0,-1.5);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Instruments has added sign symbols, voltage source arrows ...

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0)   to [rmeter,t=A,v={~}]   ++ (2,0)
                to [generic=R]          ++ (2,0)
        (0,0)   to [short,-*]           ++ (0.0,1.5)  coordinate (v)
                to [rmeter,-*,t=V,v={~}]   ++ (4,0)
        (v)     to [short]              ++ (0,1.5)
                to [V=E, name=Ve]       ++ (4,0)
                to [short,-*]           ++ (0,-1.5)
                -- ++ (0,-1.5);
\draw[->] (Ve.sw) -- (Ve.ne);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
In electrical engineering such shems are usually drawn such, that the common  (ground) potential is at bottom of shems:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0)   to [V=$E$, invert]  ++(0,4)
                to [short,-*]       ++ (1.5,0)  coordinate (v)
                -- ++ (0,-1) to [rmeterwa, t=V,v={~}] ++ (0,-2) % that +/- signs are 
                                                                % closed to V-meter
                             to [short,-*] ++ (0,-1)                
        (v)     to [short]          ++ (1.5,0)
                to [generic, a=R]   ++ (0,-2)
                to [rmeterwa,t=A,v={~}]  ++ (0,-2)
                -- (0,0)
               ;                
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I change the direction of point on A and V?

Comment: I want like my picture. Could you give me to recover this code ?

Comment: please give a recommendation to me

Comment: @PetterGreen, sorry, I do not understand your comments. What direction you like to change* BTW, in electrical engineering you scheme is usually drab  rotated for 90 degree ....

Comment: I want to get like my photo .Could you help me ?

Comment: I'm sorry, if the first solution is not enough similar to what you like to have. Package `circuitikz doesn't support unstandardized symbols.

Comment: Ok thank for your help